# SQLalchemy, how can I filter a list property from a query?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my SQLalchemy code, i have this query:

```
projectQuery = ProjectModel.query.filter(ProjectModel.isDeleted.is_(False))
```

and ProjectModel is defined like, for example:

```
    __tablename__ = 'project'
    __table_args__ = (Index('project_deleted_uc', 'name', 'clientId', unique=True,
                            postgresql_where=Column('isDeleted').is_(False)),)
    callbacks = {}
    serialize_only = ('id', 'name', 'isActive', 'client.id', 'client.name',
                      'teams.teamId', 'teams.teamName', 'teams.colorCode', 'members.memberId', 'members.memberName',
                      'members.roleId', 'members.roleName', 'members.isOtherResource', 'members.avatar')
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    isActive = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    isDeleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, server_default="false")
    clientId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("client.id"), nullable=False)
    client = db.relationship('ClientModel', back_populates='projects')
    companyId = column_property(select(ClientModel.companyId).where(ClientModel.id == clientId).as_scalar())
    clientName = column_property(select(ClientModel.name).where(ClientModel.id == clientId).as_scalar())
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('name', 'clientId', name='company_project_uc'),)

    @hybrid_property
    def teams(self):
        return ProjectTeamLinkModel.query.filter(ProjectTeamLinkModel.projectId == self.id).all()

    @teams.setter
    def teams(self, teams):
        existingTeamIds = set([r.teamId for r in self.teams])
        elementsToRemove = list(existingTeamIds - set(teams))
        elementsToInsert = list(set(teams) - existingTeamIds)
        if len(elementsToRemove):
            teamsToDelete = ProjectTeamLinkModel.query.filter(
                ProjectTeamLinkModel.projectId == self.id,
                ProjectTeamLinkModel.teamId.in_(elementsToRemove))
            for team in teamsToDelete:
                team.delete(commit=False)
        for teamId in elementsToInsert:
            ProjectTeamLinkModel(projectId=self.id, teamId=teamId).save(commit=False)
```

The query will return a list of ProjectModel values, each one having a 'teams' property which is a list of ProjectTeamLinkModel values. How can i filter this entire query so that each project will only have teams in the 'teams' list that are also in this query:

```
temporaryQuery1 = TeamMemberLinkModel.query.with_entities(
            TeamMemberLinkModel.teamId.label("teamId")).filter(
            TeamMemberLinkModel.memberId == memberId)
```